# Laravel built in user managment alteration

Tags: php, laravel-5

Can laravel built in login/register system changed so any registered user able to add more users. Currently if user logged that user not able to go to register page.Any hint will be really appreciated.

Tried this in auth controller constructor

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout', 'getRegister', 'postRegister']);
    }
```

'**getRegister**', '**postRegister**' excluded from auth. But this is not the solution. Problem still exists.

Routes

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Your routes doesn't have any names (example: 'as' => 'getRegister'), and the list in the middleware goes after the names and not the function names i think?

Comment: good catch. but thats doesn't solve the problem. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Is there anything in the Controller or function that checks for Auth? Or can't you just move them out of the middleware?